# Firestore Rules to restrict write access to a specific field in a document

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Stripe for payments. For this, I have the following data model in Firestore:

```
Users/{userId}/payments/{document}
```

each `{document}` is an object that looks like:

```
{
  amount: 55
  token: {...}
  charge: {...}
}
```

Users must be able to to write the `token` field (this is what gets passed to the server), but I don't want users to be able to write the `charge` field.

Currently my rules allow any user to read and write to this document:

```
match /payments/{documents} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

What Firestore Rules will achieve my desired security?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738514/firestore-security-for-the-update-of-specific-field-within-document
-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922055/cloud-firestore-security-rules-single-protected-field-in-a-document

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe something along the following would work, it allows clients to update fields except for charge, as well as create documents that don't have the charge field.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function valid_create() {
        return !(request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(["charge"]));
    }

    function valid_update() {
        return request.resource.data.charge == resource.data.charge
               || (valid_create()
                  && !(resource.data.keys().hasAll(["charge"])))
    }

    match /payments/{userId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId
                        && valid_create(); 
        allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId
                        && valid_update(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're referring to `userId` but it's not defined. For clarity you might want to change `{database}` to `{userId}`.

Comment: Great answer. I'd only update the `valid_create|update` methods with a check for an admin user namely: `return request.auth.token.role === 'admin' && !(request.resource...)`

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer does not work on `update`, in which `request.resource.data` returns a new map that's already merged with existing data. Because of that, `request.resource.data.keys().hasAll([<<field>>])` always return `true`.

Regardless, what works for me is using [`.diff()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map):

```js
function meta_is_modified() {
      return 'meta' in resource.data.diff(request.resource.data).affectedKeys();
    }
```

Here's another version with multiple protected fields:

```js
function invalid_modification() {
  return resource.data.diff(request.resource.data).affectedKeys().hasAny(['field1', 'field2'].toSet());
}
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

[Set type](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#december_9_2019) was announced, along with some other cool stuff.

---

Using Sets to ensure that a document only has fields "a", "b", and "c":

```
request.resource.data.keys().toSet() == ["a", "b", "c"].toSet()
```

Similarly, you could make sure that a document only has specified keys, but not others:

```
(request.resource.data.keys().toSet() - ["required","and","opt","keys"].toSet()).size == 0?`
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the redirection to set type, it helps a lot.
In my project I had to validate requests with any authorized key (one, many or all), but no extra key.

Here is what I did ; maybe it could help :

```
(request.resource.data.keys().toSet().intersection(
    ["a","b","c","d"].toSet()
)).size() == request.resource.data.keys().toSet().size();
```

Basicaly, I compared set and the intersection between my request set keys and a set which contained authorized keys. Since I wanted all the request fields to match those keys, primary set and intersection set must be equals.